# When is the sine of radians and degrees the same?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I need to find the two smallest positive values of $x$ such that $$sin(x °) = sin(x)$$. This is what I did. First, I converted degrees to radians by doing $x ° = {x\pi \over 180}$. So our starting equation becomes  $$sin({\pi x \over 180}) = sin(x)$$, which becomes $$sin({\pi x \over 180}) = sin(x +2\pi n)$$ for an integer $n$. Now, I invert both sides to get $${x\pi \over 180} = x+2\pi n \implies x\pi=180x+360\pi n \implies x={360\pi n \over \pi -180} $$. Thus, we get our two smallest positive values of $x$ when we input $n=-1,-2$, to get $$x= {360\pi (-1) \over \pi -180},{360\pi (-2) \over \pi -180}$$, which are approximately $$x= 6.39, 12.79$$. However, a simple graph on desmos shows that my solutions aren't the smallest. Wolfram tells us that these solutions are given by $${-180 π\over180 + π} + {360 n π \over 180 + π}$$. I do not understand how they got this, though, any help is appreciated. [image]

Comment: You have oversimplified the problem by (wrongly) assuming that ${x\pi \over 180} = x+2\pi n$.  This assumption wrongly assumes (for example) that given $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sin(x_1) = \sin(x_2)$ that $(2\pi)$ must divide $(x_1 - x_2)$.  This is flat wrong.  As a simple example, $\sin(\pi/4) = \sin(3\pi/4).$  Take a look at the graph of $y = \sin(x)$.

Comment: It may in fact turn out that no solution is possible except ${x\pi \over 180} = x+2\pi n$, but you can't really assume that, unless you can prove it.  If you can't prove it, you have to investigate other possibilities.

Comment: I see @user2661923, how about sin(x) = sin(pi - x +2pi * n)

Comment: Cart before the horse; don't be in a hurry, and stop guessing.  The basic equation is $\sin\left({x\pi \over 180}\right) = \sin(x).$  Also, the first line of your query is (also) wrong.  You are (presumably) looking for the smallest positive number (one number, not two numbers) $x$ such that $\sin(x^\circ) = \sin(x ~\text{radians}).$  Take it one slow careful step at a time.

Comment: @user2661923 I am looking for two numbers in fact

Comment: If you examine the graph of $\sin(x),$ it is clear that in the interval $0 < x < \pi/2, ~~\sin(x)$ is strictly increasing.  So what you want is for $x^\circ$ to be some small number less than $3.14159$ such that $x$ radians is between $(\pi/2)$ and $(\pi).$  Realizing that this is what you want is the first major hurdle in the problem.

Comment: Oh, okay, so you are looking for $x_1, x_2$ such that $\sin([x_1]^\circ) = \sin([x_1] ~\text{radians})$ and $\sin([x_2]^\circ) = \sin([x_2] ~\text{radians})$.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: The smallest ones that are positive, yes, also no absolute value @user2661923

Comment: The comments that I made pertain to $0 < x_1 < 3.14159$.  Unclear, once you find $x_1$, how you will find $x_2$.

Comment: It seems clear to me, that for $x_1,$ you want $(180^\circ - [x_1]^\circ) = (x_1 ~\text{radians}).$

Comment: If you are in fact also looking for the *next* satisfying value $x_2$, I suspect that $x_2$ will be between $(4\pi/2)$ and $(5\pi/2)$, so that (in effect) $[x_2]^\circ$ will be approximately $(6.3)^\circ.$

Comment: Look at the [graphs](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwryMkv0dAozszTqNDUUQDTWgWZ-oYWBppAvoaBjoIxkA9klmQmZxfbAqVMIOz4tPyi3MSSktQioKAmAPtWFhE=&lang=sage)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\sin A=\sin B$, the [identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3171404/215011)
$$\sin A-\sin B=2\sin\left(\frac{A-B}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{A+B}2\right)\tag1$$
implies that
$$
 \sin\left(\frac{A-B}2\right)= 0\qquad\text{or}\qquad\cos\left(\frac{A+B}2\right)=0,\tag2
$$
which is the same as saying
$$
\qquad\frac {A-B}2=n\pi\qquad\text{or}\qquad\frac{A+B}2 = \frac\pi2+k\pi,\tag3$$
for some integer choices of $n$ and $k$.

In your case $A:=\frac{x\pi}{180}$ and $B:=x$. Your solution has got only the first half of (3). Actually the Wolfram solution is the other half (you need to replace $k$ with $n-1$ to get their solution), and is also incomplete. You'll need to plug various values of $n$ and $k$ into (3) to find the smallest two positive solutions.